# AppCenter can't update Flatpak packages

Tags: updates, appcenter, release-hera, crash, flatpak

Since yesterday, when I try to update those two recommended items, the process fails and the updates are still showing. Sometimes, but not always, AppCenter crashes and closes.
[image]
All other updates are working fine, I am on Hera 5.1, Dell XPS 9550.

Anyone else and/or ideas?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

After having tried the latest answer with no luck, I tried this:

```
edo@XPS:~$ flatpak install org.gnome.platform
Looking for matches…
Found similar ref(s) for ‘org.gnome.platform’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user).
Use this remote? [Y/n]: Y
Similar refs found for ‘org.gnome.platform’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user):

   1) runtime/org.gnome.Platform.Compat.i386/x86_64/3.34
   2) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.24
   3) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.28
   4) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.26
   5) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.32
   6) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.30
   7) runtime/org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-7]: 7
Skipping: org.gnome.Platform/x86_64/3.34 is already installed
edo@XPS:~$ flatpak install org.kde.platform
Looking for matches…
Found similar ref(s) for ‘org.kde.platform’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user).
Use this remote? [Y/n]: Y
Similar refs found for ‘org.kde.platform’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user):

   1) runtime/org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform/x86_64/5.9
   2) runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.12
   3) runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.13
   4) runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.10
   5) runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.11
   6) runtime/org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform/x86_64/5.10
   7) runtime/org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform/x86_64/5.13
   8) runtime/org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform/x86_64/5.11
   9) runtime/org.kde.PlatformTheme.QGnomePlatform/x86_64/5.12
  10) runtime/org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.9

Which do you want to use (0 to abort)? [0-10]: 3
Skipping: org.kde.Platform/x86_64/5.13 is already installed
```

No luck either though.

At this point, if no one else if affected by this and there is no solution, I hope that the next time those packages will be updated, it will automatically work. Hopefully? Maybe? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have the same situation since yesterday morning. So far I haven't any solution but I found this:

According to [Hector R on this issue on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/freedesktop-sdk/freedesktop-sdk/issues/886)

> Step1
>
> `flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08`
>
> Step2
>
> `flatpak uninstall --unused`
>
> Step3
>
> `flatpak update`
>
> NOTE: in the latest step maybe the system update some packages and ask
>   for download what you need and YES. After update the new packages run
>   again flatpak update
>
> Then reboot.
>
> That's it
>
> Hope helps.

And after this my AppCenter says "No components with updates" so looks like the problem is solved.

Regards, swnw

Comment: Cheers, thank you for your help. Sadly, no luck but your reply helped me to try something else, see my above edit.

Comment: @swnw Thanks. After I tried the edited solution mentioned by the OP (minus the kde part). In my case updating the gnome platform involved installing some other stuff as well, which were detected as missing during the installation process. Then after all that I tried your suggestion and it worked for me. +1  The Flatpak is no longer hanging in the AppCenter update queue.

Comment: Same here! After the above comment comment I tried this again and it worked! Thanks a lot, I hated having those pending updates (OCD much? :D )

Answer (score 2):

what I recommend you is to try to do this using command lines. Open your terminal application and execute

```
flatpak update
```

**! without sudo**, otherwise you will receive an error message. Another option that works for me in a bit complicated situations is `sudo flatpak repair`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what happened with both, I still have the notification in the AppCenter:

edo@XPS:~$ sudo flatpak repair
          
Working on the system installation at /var/lib/flatpak
Segmentation fault
edo@XPS:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…
        ID                                           Branch           Op           Remote            Download
 1. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264            19.08            i            flathub           593,6 kB / 593,4 kB

Warning: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 not installed
Installation complete.

Comment: I think this might relate to my problem, maybe? https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/2116

Comment: I have a lot of flatpak applications, but I don't have any problems with this. I received the same request for updates and I did the update from the appCenter with no issues. You are not the only one who has this problem, I do not have any KDE application from flatpak, this is the only difference - it may be the cost of the problem, but your response of the repair command is the same as the one the others having the same problem gives me.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. I really don't have much flatpaks, just Telegram and Dropbox. If enter the command flatpak list, some other stuff pops up but I think they have been installed in relation to Telegram and/or Dropbox. I tried to remove those two problematic packages and the Dropbox & Telegram apps, but reinstalling everything recreated the problem. Would love to use the official AppCenter versions of those two apps, but they are so outdated.

Answer (score 1):

@Travis So the conclusion is "No luck either though.". 
Actually it's my first time when I had update elementary os trouble. I think that elementary os creators should read elementaryos.stackexchange.com from time to time ;). Faltpak in their opinion is "the  future for our AppCenter ecosystem".So I try to send them this link of troubles. Not so easy I'm trying to find, I thought. simple thing "the contact" :/. I have no Facebook and Twitter accounts - I deleted them, so I have no chance.

Regards, swnw.

Comment: Yeah, I will try to submit this to the devs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved the flatpak update issue.

**Update faltpak in Terminal.**

```
flatpak update
```

One package `org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.default` found but got error when update.

**List the installed package.**

```
flatpak list
```

I found the same package is installed.

**Uninstall that package.**

```
flatpak uninstall [Application ID]
```

**Update flatpak and it success.**

```
flatpak update
```

Problem solved.

** Please confirm if it's a correct way. I'm only a normal user and not familiar which what I said above.