# "org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime" update fails to install

Tags: updates

"org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime" has been showing for the last few days in app centre as an system update but everytime I try to update the app centre crashes.
Re-opening the app centre and no results can be found for installed apps.
Installed apps only appear after system shutdown and restart and "org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime" is back there as a system update.
Ignored it expecting "a fix" to appear but none so far and now there are other updates that appear to be not updating I assume due to the failure of "org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime" "crashing" app centre.

anyone got any similar experience /solutions???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AppCenter can't update Flatpak packages](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/appcenter-cant-update-flatpak-packages)

Comment: This [answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/22022/15156) from another question might help you. It basically involves using Flatpak to perform the required update, instead of AppCenter.