# UPDATED: org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime STILL not updating

Tags: updates, appcenter, flatpak

Yesterday there were 9 system upgrades in the AppCenter. I upgraded, but org.gnome.Platform Flatpak runtime was still listed.
I tried again, and it remains there waiting for upgrade.
Also might maybe be relevant to mention: since some days after I press the upgrade button it starts immediately to fill the blue bar (downloading, installing etc) WITHOUT ASKING for the authentication, as usually. After that it does NOT crash, as it did some time ago, but it also does NOT update. Flatpak runtime remains there, AppCenter remains open, update button is visible.

Today I tried the solution suggested on the chosen answer of [this thread](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/22008/appcenter-cant-update-flatpak-packages) and here's the terminal output:

master@elm:~$ flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08
Looking for matches…
Found similar ref(s) for ‘org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08’ in remote ‘flathub’ (user).
Use this remote? [Y/n]: y

```
    ID                                  Branch   Op   Remote   Download
```

1. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale     19.08    i    flathub   16,7 kB / 318,2 MB

2. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264   19.08    i    flathub  593,6 kB / 593,4 kB
3. [✓] org.freedesktop.Platform            19.08    i    flathub   11,4 MB / 238,1 MB

Warning: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 not installed
Installation complete.

master@elm:~$ flatpak uninstall --unused

```
    ID                                              Branch          Op
```

1. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.VAAPI.Intel            18.08           r

2. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.html5-codecs           18.08           r
3. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform                        19.08           r
4. [-] org.freedesktop.Platform.Locale                 19.08           r
5. [-] org.gnome.Platform                              3.32            r
6. [-] org.gnome.Platform.Locale                       3.32            r

Uninstall complete.

master@elm:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…

```
    ID                                  Branch   Op   Remote   Download
```

1. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264   19.08    i    flathub  593,6 kB / 593,4 kB

Warning: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 not installed
Installation complete.

master@elm:~$ sudo apt install org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264
[sudo] password for master:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264'

master@elm:~$ sudo flatpak repair
Working on the system installation at /var/lib/flatpak
Segmentation fault

master@elm:~$ flatpak update
Looking for updates…

```
    ID                                  Branch   Op   Remote   Download
```

1. [✗] org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264   19.08    i    flathub  593,6 kB / 593,4 kB

Warning: org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264 not installed
Installation complete.

UPDATE (March 17, 2020): It's getting worse. Today there were several system components to update, plus the above mentioned gnome Platform, plus two new gnome Platform.Locale. After installing most of them, the AppCenter crashed. 
I started it again, tried to update again, it updated one library (don't recall the name) and crashed again. 
[image: screenshot before the last update]
Tried it yet again, and the two.Locale updated, this time without crashing, but the old one is still there and the update button is gone. After closing the AppCenter and opening it again, the button is back but 1) it doesn't ask for the password  before start 'updating' and 2) doesn't change a thing, file is still listed in there.
[image: org.gnome.Platform runtime remains]

Comment: Same issues.   Just started today.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.

```
flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/19.08
```

Step 2.

```
flatpak uninstall --unused
```

Step 3.

```
flatpak update
```

NOTE: in the latest step maybe the system update some packages and ask for download what you need and YES. After update the new packages run again flatpak update

Then reboot.

**OR**

```
sudo flatpak repair
```